# Laravel4 Model::all() not working

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Could anyone pls help, why the first $eq will causes a 500 error ?
Thank you in advance.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('page', function()
{

        $eq = Equip_for_sale::all();                // Not Working !
        $eq = DB::table('equip_for_sale')->get();   // Working !
        return View::make('page')->with('eq', $eq);
});
```

**models/Equip_for_sale.php**

```
   class Equip_for_sale extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'equip_for_sale';

    }
```

**views/page.php**

`var_dump($eq);`

Comment: Take a look at your webserver (apache?) logs, it must tell you what's going in that line.

Comment: it says "Class 'xxx' not found in C:\...". thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel expecting `StudlyCaps` class name as `Laravel` follow `PSR` coding standard.

According to the `PSR` coding style:

```
Class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps and Method names MUST be declared in camelCase.
```

https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md
https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

so,

```
class EquipForSale extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'equip_for_sale';

    }
```

and in your controller:

```
$eq = EquipForSale::all();
```